# when i try to start a rails server, i get an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

this is the error

```
C:\Users\Евгений\silmple_cms2>rails server
C:/Users/Евгений/silmple_cms2/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uni
nitialized constant Bundler (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/com
mands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:128:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_req
uire.rb:39:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

C:\Users\Евгений\silmple_cms2>
```

Comment: you don't seem to have `bundler` installed. try `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `bundler` is not present. Before starting server, try:

```
gem install bundler
```

followed by:

```
rails server
```

Incase `bundler` is already present, clear all `bundler` specific settings and caches:

```
rm -rf .bundle/
rm -rf vendor/
rm -rf Gemfile.lockcache/
```

Answer (score 0):

Type:
`gem install bundler`
to install the bundler application which handles all the gems.

And then type `bundler install` to go through and install all the gems.

Comment: are you using Capistrano?

Comment: i am not using  Capistrano